# onSubmit validation issue in React form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, validation

I have a simple setup for validating a few form entries. It only pushes validation for the first entry. So in state I have:

```
this.state = {
  username: '',
  email: '',
  zip: '',
  errors:[]
}
```

The `submit` button:

```
<div>
  <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}
     >submit
  </button>
</div>
```

The submit button and the form both trigger `handleSubmit`:

```
handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({errors:[]});
    const {username, email, zip} = this.state;
    const errors = validate(username, email, zip);
    if (errors.length>0) {
      this.setState({errors});
    }
}
```

which hits `validate`:

```
function validate(username, email, zip) {
  let validEmail = RegExp(/[^@ \t\r\n]+@[^@ \t\r\n]+\.[^@ \t\r\n]+/);
  let validZip = RegExp(/^\d{5}$/);
  const errors = [];
  if (username.length < 3 || null) {
    errors.push('Name must be at least 3 characters long.');
  }
  if (validEmail.test(email)) {
    errors.push('Email address must be valid email address.');
  }
  if (validZip.test(zip)) {
      errors.push('Zip code must be 5 digits.')
  }
  console.log(errors);
  return errors;
}
```

and then, from the updated state, errors are supposed to print as line items in:

```
<ul className="errorList">
   {this.state.errors.map(
        (error => 
            <li key={error}>
                {error}
            </li>
        )
    )}
</ul>
```

but only the first validation is working (for `username`), in a console log and in the unordered list.

Looking for advice ^~^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`validEmail.test(email)` return `false`, try `!validEmail.test(email)` will return `true` if email failed

Comment: Also, check the testing `zip` part, the same problem occurs there, too.